# DOORS Layout DXL is reporting each link twice

Tags: ibm-doors

I'm using the Analysis Wizard to create a LayoutDXL column which should list attributes (e.g. AbsoluteNumber) for each existing In-link in my current module.  In one particular DOORS module,  the resulting DXL code displays each of these attributes twice.  This doesn't happen in other modules.

I did notice that the offending module doesn't have a defined set of LinkModules (as seen in File/ModuleProperties).  Could that be causing some sort of loopback?

### Update:

I've discovered that somehow the DXL code "thinks" there are two versions of a defined LinkModule, i.e. "Current" and "Baseline X" . These each link to different baseline numbers in the target DOORS module.  I don't know how to fix that.

For reference, here's the DXL code generated with the Wizard.  This is DOORS 9.6.1.11

```
// DXL generated by DOORS traceability wizard on 12 February 2019.
// Wizard version 2.0, DOORS version 9.6.1.11
pragma runLim, 0
string limitModules[1] = {"[serial number redacted]"}
void showIn(Object o, int depth) {
    Link l
    LinkRef lr
    ModName_ otherMod = null
    Module linkMod = null
    ModuleVersion otherVersion = null
    Object othero
    string disp = null
    string s = null
    string plain, plainDisp
    int plainTextLen
    int count
    bool doneOne = false
    string linkModName = "*"
    for lr in all(o<-linkModName) do {
        otherMod = module (sourceVersion lr)
        if (!null otherMod) {
            if ((!isDeleted otherMod) && (null data(sourceVersion lr))) {
                if (!equal(getItem otherMod, (itemFromID limitModules[depth-1]))) continue
                load((sourceVersion lr),false)
            }
        }
    }
    for l in all(o<-linkModName) do {
        otherVersion = sourceVersion l
        otherMod = module(otherVersion)
        if (null otherMod || isDeleted otherMod) continue
        if (!equal(getItem otherMod, (itemFromID limitModules[depth-1]))) continue
        othero = source l
        if (null othero) {
            load(otherVersion,false)
        }
        othero = source l
        if (null othero) continue
        if (isDeleted othero) continue
        doneOne = true
        if (depth == 1) {
            s = probeRichAttr_(othero,"Absolute Number", false)
            if (s == "") 
            displayRich("\\pard " " ")
            else
            displayRich("\\pard " s)
            s = probeRichAttr_(othero,"Object Heading", false)
            if (s == "") 
            displayRich("\\pard " " ")
            else
            displayRich("\\pard " s)
        }
    }
}
showIn(obj,1)
```

Comment: about your update: is there really a baseline of your link module? Or are there different baselines of your outgoing module that link to the current version of your ingoing module? In this case, I would say that the result is "correct", whatever this means. If you want only the in link from the current version, you could adopt the script by looking at the version of the module of the incoming link. But your solution as of course also OK

Comment: @Mike  There's only one "physical" link module and one "physical" each Parent and Child requirements module.  Somehow the internal baselines (vs. "current" ) appear to have got mucked up.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the situation where objects DID have two links between them, this is possible with different link modules (Object 1 of Module A SATISFIES Object 2 of Module B and Object 1 of Module A REFINES Object 2 of Module B). While there may be reasons for such a situation, most often this is caused by a "link move" script that was not used correctly.

You should augment your code by displaying the name of the link module as well (variable linkModName). Perhaps this shows the reason for your observation

Comment: Thanks - but I did check and there's only the one link.  Running the Wizard on the far end (for out-links)  works as expected.